# How do I remove 1 instance of x characters in a string and find the word it makes in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

This is what I have so far, but I'm stuck.  I'm using nltk for the word list and trying to find all the words with the letters in "sand".  From this list I want to find all the words I can make from the remaining letters.

```
import nltk.corpus.words.words()
pwordlist = []

for w in wordlist:
    if 's' in w:
        if 'a' in w:
            if 'n' in w:
                if 'd' in w:
                    pwordlist.append(w)
```

In this case I have to use all the letters to find the words possible.
I think this will work for finding the possible words with the remaining letters, but I can't figure out how to remove only 1 instance of the letters in 'sand'.

```
puzzle_letters = nltk.FreqDist(x)

[w for w in pwordlist if len(w) = len(pwordlist) and nltk.FreqDist(w) = puzzle_letters]
```

Comment: Can you give a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of `w = w.replace("s", "", 1).replace("a", "", 1).....`

Comment: I want to find all the words with those letters included.  Then I want to remove the letters "sand", and find only words that can be made with all the letters remaining.  
So if I have "sandcastle", "sandwich",and "sadness" 
I want it to return "sand" "castle".
I don't care if it is in a dictionary, or list or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would separate the logic into four sections:

1. A function `contains(word, letters)`, which we'll use to detect whether a word contains "sand"
2. A function `subtract(word, letters)`, which we'll use to remove "sand" from the word.
3. A function `get_anagrams(word)`, which finds all of the anagrams of a word.
4. The main algorithm that combines all of the above to find words that are anagrams of other words once you remove "sand".

```
from collections import Counter

words = ??? #todo: somehow get a list of every English word.

def contains(word, letters):
    return not Counter(letters) - Counter(word)

def subtract(word, letters):
    remaining = Counter(word) - Counter(letters)
    return "".join(remaining.elements())

anagrams = {}
for word in words:
    base = "".join(sorted(word))
    anagrams.setdefault(base, []).append(word)
def get_anagrams(word):
    return anagrams.get("".join(sorted(word)), [])

for word in words:
    if contains(word, "sand"):
        reduced_word = subtract(word, "sand")
        matches = get_anagrams(reduced_word)
        if matches:
            print word, matches
```

Running the above code on the Words With Friends dictionary, I get a lot of results, including:

```
...
cowhands ['chow']
credentials ['reticle', 'tiercel']
cyanids ['icy']
daftness ['efts', 'fest', 'fets']
dahoons ['oho', 'ooh']
daikons ['koi']
daintiness ['seniti']
daintinesses ['sienites']
dalapons ['opal']
dalesman ['alme', 'lame', 'male', 'meal']
...
```

Comment: That is amazing!  Thank you very much.  I've been fighting with this thing for days now and you provided a solution in less time than it took me to ASK the question.

Comment: I only made two changes to the code for Python 3,  I added the () to print, and changed iteritems() to items().  And it worked perfectly.  Thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: I compared our solutions with those nltk.corpus.words. Looks good, we found the exact same results (mine took 4.4 seconds, yours 15.9 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

Program:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
from collections import defaultdict

def norm(word):
    return ''.join(sorted(word))

completers = defaultdict(list)
for word in words.words():
    completers[norm(word + 'sand')].append(word)

for word in words.words():
    comps = completers[norm(word)]
    if comps:
        print(word, comps)
```

Output:

```
...
admirableness ['miserable']
adnascent ['enact']
adroitness ['sorite', 'sortie', 'triose']
adscendent ['cedent', 'decent']
adsorption ['portio']
adventuress ['vesture']
adversant ['avert', 'tarve', 'taver', 'trave']
...
```

Comment: Nice approach. Adding "sand" instead of subtracting definitely seems less computationally expensive.

Comment: @Kevin And simpler :-)

Comment: I'm trying to follow the code through, but I'm confused on why you chose to add, and why this code is less computationally expensive.  As you can tell I am very much a novice at this.

Comment: I chose it because it's simpler :-). Adding a string to another is just `+`. Why is it faster? @Kevin's `contains` is rather costly. Replacing it with `set('sand') <= set(word)` actually makes it faster than mine, but that only works because "sand" doesn't have duplicate letters.

Comment: That said, he could do `set('sand') <= set(word) and contains(...)`. That's both fast and correct. But also even more complicated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer your question instead of spoiling the fun by doing the whole exercise for you: To remove just one instance of the letter, specify a replacement and give a limit to how many times it should apply:

```
>>> "Frodo".replace("o", "", 1)
'Frdo'
```

Or if you need to apply a regexp just once (though in this case you don't need a regexp):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"[od]", "", "Frodo", 1)
'Frdo'
```

Now if you have a string whose letters (s, a, n, d) you want to remove from a word `word`, you can simply loop over the string:

```
>>> for letter in "sand":
        word = word.replace(letter, "", word)
```

I'll leave it to you to embed this in a loop that goes over all words in your wordlist, and to utilize the remaining letters.